# How to export multiple STIX2 bundles?

Tags: json, export

I have been working on Threat Feed Recently, I am trying to export all the threats that I have found on my system as STIX2 format.

I have gone through the it's documentation and I have created the Stix2 bundles. Now I am trying to figure out the way to export all the bundles to one file so that this file can be used in threat feeds, For instance splunk is a tool that allows to read this stix feed.

A single bundle looks like this.

```
{"type":"bundle","id":"bundle--92bf6237-1b3d-43f9-85d7-e31c0b3f11b7","spec_version":"2.0","objects":[{"id":"indicator--c68d9454-32e3-4f30-8321-a6758df83877","type":"indicator","created":"2017-10-27T00:00:00.000Z","modified":"2017-10-27T00:00:00.000Z","name":"File hash for malware variant","pattern":"[file:hashes.md5 = 'a5ef29d5315111c80a5c1abad14c8972']","valid_from":"2017-10-27T00:00:00.000Z","labels":["malicious-activity"]},{"type":"malware","id":"malware--0e1f009a-0e6c-437e-a1ec-0c003522b1d3","created":"2017-10-27T00:00:00.000Z","modified":"2017-10-27T00:00:00.000Z","name":"Malware","labels":["remote-access-trojan"]},{"type":"relationship","id":"relationship--c17cf161-4ec2-471c-ac58-4a1cf6e0964f","created":"2017-10-27T00:00:00.000Z","modified":"2017-10-27T00:00:00.000Z","relationship_type":"indicates","source_ref":"indicator--c68d9454-32e3-4f30-8321-a6758df83877","target_ref":"malware--0e1f009a-0e6c-437e-a1ec-0c003522b1d3"}]}
```

Now I have multiple bundles how can I export them?

Answer (score 0):

In a TAXII feed, it is one STIX2 bundle per content block. You can use [OpenTAXII](https://opentaxii.readthedocs.io) server (supports TAXII 1.1 and is content agnostic) to serve that feed to your Splunk instance.

If you read data from files, store every bundle in a separate JSON file.